# Elastic Search : Consecutive Page navigation using spring-data-elasticsearch results empty after certain limit

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

1. Using the rest-clients /_search?size=100&from=500, able to fetch the results

   Same doesnt work with below step using the code
2. Using the **spring-data-elasticsearch with following below code snippets 
   On using the size=100, from=500, results are empty**

   Note : It fetched results successfully only one time, i.e after the index-creation

   ```
   NativeSearchQueryBuilder nativeSearchQueryBuilder = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder();

   nativeSearchQueryBuilder.withIndices("indexName");
   nativeSearchQueryBuilder.withTypes("someType");
   nativeSearchQueryBuilder.withPageable(new PageRequest(500, 100));
   SearchQuery searchQuery = nativeSearchQueryBuilder.build();
   elasticsearchTemplate.queryForList(searchQuery,
               className);
   ```

   Do we need to add any extra step to the above snippets to get the desired results ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`PageRequest` constructor](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-data-commons/current-SNAPSHOT/api/org/springframework/data/domain/PageRequest.html) does not take `from` and `size` as arguments, but `page` and `size` which is different, because `page` and `from` are not the same.

If you want your pages to contain 100 elements, then instead of `from=500` you need to use `page=5`

```
 nativeSearchQueryBuilder.withPageable(new PageRequest(5, 100));
```

Comment: Thanks understood, its correct, why elastic search api doesnt have such support, same is supported from restclient ?

Comment: It's the same thing just implemented differently, just page+size instead of from+size. `PageRequest` comes from Spring Data Core and is an abstraction to suit any kind of underlying datastore (ES, JPA, MongoDB Cassandra, etc). Under the hood, `PageRequest` uses from/size as well when used against Elasticsearch.

Comment: Thanks @Val for the detailed explanation